# Using mongodb native function via mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, function, go, mongo-go-driver

Just as the title, how does one use mongo-go-driver to execute mongodb's native function, such as `ISODate().getTime()`? I can't find a good docs, even in mongo's official docs, to do this.

For example, query

```
db.coll.update({key: 'random-id'}, {$set: {last_seen: ISODate().getTime()}})
```

Roughly translate to

```
coll.updateOne(
    ctx,
    bson.D{
       bson.E{Key: "key", Value: "random-id"},
    },
    bson.D{
       bson.E{Key: "last_seen", Value: "ISODate().getTime()"},
    }
)
```

but that way, the last seen value wont be a UNIX timestamp in mongo, but literal string "ISODate().getTime()"

Notes: For the dummy case, preferably not have to create the timestamp in the application level, so need to use DB's function

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The code you are trying to use is mongo shell code. You need to construct the command using Go because you are programming in Go, not in mongo shell.

Comment: I give the example in BOTH mongo shell and golang

Comment: Your go example is not functional for the reason I described.

Comment: I have written `roughly`, but my point still stands that no way to use native function